# Update document after index rollup in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index (lets say named "data") template and ILP causing index to rollup when some conditions are met. This causes indexes data-000001, data-000002, etc. to appear.
All those indexes are grouped using alias as "data" so I can execute searches covering all of them. Thats fine.

I need, in some moments, to update documents. I have tried the "_update" API
however, if I pass the alias to that API it only targets the latest index.
I may don't know in which index a specific document is located (thats the reason to use alias).

Is there a way to request an update on a document without passing the index?

Answer (score 0):

try use `_update` on a `wildcard` format if your indices names is somethings like data-000x use the `data*/_update` be sure you don't have other indices that start with data word so you don't impact other documents

Comment: I have found that `_update_by_query` solves the problem. Do you know anything that might make `data*/_update` a better option?

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I have found that

`POST /messages/_update_by_query`

will process the alias name correctly and work as expected.

This is because this is an update operation that is backed by a query
so, since the queries works well across the indexes that are part of an alias, then this operation `_update_by_query` works as well.